# Unity: Manage AudioManager on all scenes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the create an `AudioManager` with the following code:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine;

public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Sound[] sounds;

    public static AudioManager instance;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    public void Play(SoundType soundType)
    {
        Sound s = Array.Find(this.sounds, sound => sound.soundType == soundType);

        s.source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        s.source.clip = s.clip;

        // We define volume and pitch here to be able to change them in real time
        s.source.volume = s.volume;
        s.source.pitch = s.pitch;
        s.source.Play();
    }
}
```

It works really well as long as I start it on the scene the `gameObject` (containing this `MonoBehaviour`) is defined on.
However, for some debug purposes, I do start some scenes alone, and the `gameObject` containing the `AudioManager` isn't defined. How should I get around this issue ?

Comment: every time you play a sound you add a compoent?? that sounds, somewhat unnecessary

Comment: However, what if I need to perform the same sound several times at the same moment ?

Comment: normally you have objects who have the component on, and its them that make the sound, not a controller (allows for things to sound to the left or right, in front or behind) ..   then each of those components makes the noise (say on death) but imagine you have a kinda never ending space invaders.. your way if I kill 20k enemies.. you have 20k components of audio source on your manager...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are two tasks:

- You need the `AudioManager` or actually better said the `AudioSource` instance to be accessible/instanced into any scene
- you want to populate a `List<Audio clip>`

In order to bring both together I would use a `ScriptableObject`

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class AudioData : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<Sound> sounds = new List<Sound>();
}
```

Create an instance by right-click in the Assets → <kbd>Create</kbd> → <kbd>AudioData</kbd>

Here you can populate the list of `Sounds`.

Then I'ld directly use your Singleton with a lazy instantiation in order to initialize one if none of found in the scene maybe even combined with [`[RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute.html)

> Methods marked `[RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]` are invoked after the game has been loaded.

This is called after all `Awake` calls are done so either an instance exists then or it will be created now.

Something like e.g.

```
public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // if you have it in the scene you can reference these right away
    [SerializeField] private AudioData audioData;
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource audioSource;

    // backing field for actually store the Singleton instance
    private static AudioManager _instance;

    // public access for the Singleton
    // and lazy instantiation if not exists
    public static AudioManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            // if exists directly return
            if(_instance) return instance;

            // otherwise search it in the scene
            _instance = FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>();

            // found it?
            if(_instance) return instance;

            // otherwise create and initialize it
            CreateInstance();

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (_instance && _instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }

        InitializeInstance(this);
    }

    [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]
    private static void CreateInstance()
    {
        // skip if already exists
        if(_instance) return;

        InitializeInstance(new GameObject (nameof(AudioManager)).AddComponent<AudioManager>());         
    }

    private static void InitializeInstance(AudioManager instance)
    {
        _instance = instance;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        if(!_instance.audioSource) _instance.audioSource = _instance.AddComponent<AudioSource>();

        if(_instance.audioData) return;

        var audioDatas = Resources.FindObjectsOfType<AudioData>();
        if(audioDatas.Length == 0)
        {
            Debug.LogError("No Instance of AudioData found! Don't forget to create that ScriptableObject!");
            return;
        }

        _instance.audioData = audioDatas[0];
    }

    public void Play(SoundType soundType)
    {
        Sound s = audioData.sounds.First(sound => sound.soundType == soundType);

        s.source = audioSource;
        s.source.clip = s.clip;

        // We define volume and pitch here to be able to change them in real time
        s.source.volume = s.volume;
        s.source.pitch = s.pitch;
        s.source.Play();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an auto constructed singleton. The first time you call `AudioManager.Instance` it will spawn a new game object and attach the `AudioManager` script to it.

```
public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    static AudioManager instance;
    public static AudioManager Instance => instance ?? (instance = new GameObject("AudioManager", typeof(AudioManager)).GetComponent<AudioManager>());

    public void PlaySound(SoundType soundType)
    {
        Debug.Log("Play Sound: " + soundType);
    }
}
```

Comment: I could do it indeed, but then how do I populate my list of sounds ?

Comment: @Scipion you could load them dynamically with ‘Resources.Load(…)’

Comment: Oh do not use the Resources folder! (See [Best practice](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#))

Comment: @derHugo feel free to elaborate.

Comment: @Iggy if you checkout the section about the [Resources folder](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7) Unity's own recommendation is **`Don't use it`** ;) reasons can be found there as well. The Resources folder *can* be used for fast prototyping but should not be used for the final implementation.

Comment: @derHugo Thanks, that was an informative read. I’ve been heavily relying on Resources for the last few prospects. I should really start using addressables.

Answer (score 0):

Make the AudioManager a singleton and access it in every scene where you need it.
Use this pattern: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton

As a note, you will *not* want to perform

```
s.source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
```

every time you play.  You will wind up with a bunch AudioSources as you play sounds.  You should check for the existence and then create it if you need it.  Also, you can get by with just one audio source if you are only playing one sound at a time.

Comment: However, what if I need to perform the same sound several times at the same moment ?

Comment: In that case, you can have multiple AudioSources.  I have an app that uses three per scene: Dialog, Music, SoundEffects.  Regardless, you should check to see if it exists before creating one.